Why is this proof about integration correct?
I have already asked about this particular integral, but I am not sure if this reasoning makes sense.
From the equality
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2-y^2}\ dxdy=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2}dy=\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx\right)^2$$
Now using polar coordinates one can find that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt{\pi}$$
My Professor then said that
$$\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}e^{-\mathbf{x}^\top A\mathbf{x}}\ d\mathbf{x}=\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}e^{-(\lambda_1\hat{x}_1^2+\cdots+\lambda_n\hat{x}_n^2)}\ d\hat{\mathbf{x}}=\frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\sqrt{\lambda_1\cdots\lambda_n}}$$
So I can see how it is related to the first integral but I do not see the maths behind it. Can somebody lend me a hand?
